# Lists of primitive congruent numbers

Tags: number-theory

Can anyone provide me with a reference to lists of primitive congruent numbers that are greater than $10^4$?

Comment: What is a "primitive congruent number"?

Comment: @lulu I think, primitive means squarefree - see [here](https://oeis.org/A006991).

Comment: @DietrichBurde  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the lists given at [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A003273) about congruent numbers, which give all congruent numbers up to $10^4$, there is the following [link](http://www.numbersaplenty.com/data/primitive-congruent-mod123.txt),  containing a list of the primitive congruent numbers up to $10^{7}$. The computation has been done using [Tunnel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunnell%27s_theorem), which assumes the [Birch-Swinnerton-Dyer conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birch_and_Swinnerton-Dyer_conjecture).

Comment: Thanks.That confirms Primorial{1,...,8} are all squarefree congruent numbers. Also Primorial {9,10} are squarefree congruent numbers as they are both equivalent to 6 Mod 8. What about Primorial(11) ? Is there a theorem/conjecture that all Primorials are squarefree congruent numbers?